# installation spring tools in eclipse kepler

Tags: spring, eclipse-kepler

i have install spring STS and Spring IDE (Eclipse Plug-in) in eclipse Kepler from Eclipse Marketplace ,
The installation process has successfully , But did not change anything in the interface, and I did not find spring project in project wizard

OS:Linux Fedora
IDE:Eclipse kepler

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Solved]
Classic way, Eclipse IDE, click “Help” -> “Install New Software…”. Type “http://springide.org/updatesite” to access the Spring IDE update site.

Select all the Spring IDE features you want to install.

Take long time to install and restart Eclipse after finished.

Answer (score 0):

We can use "Eclipse Market place" to install STS. Click “Help” -> “Eclipse Marketplace“, type “Spring IDE“, then STS will be listed. Click to install it.